# Change date format in a Java string

Tags: java, string, date, formatting, date-format

I've a `String` representing a date.

```
String date_s = "2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";
```

I'd like to convert it to a `Date` and output it in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

> 2011-01-18

How can I achieve this?

---

Okay, based on the answers I retrieved below, here's something I've tried:

```
String date_s = " 2011-01-18 00:00:00.0"; 
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"); 
Date date = dt.parse(date_s); 
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-mm-dd");
System.out.println(dt1.format(date));
```

But it outputs `02011-00-1` instead of the desired `2011-01-18`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yyyyy is not the same as yyyy.  :)

Comment: A boomerang question. What is your use case? Because it is possible that you should use built-in patterns (DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()).

Comment: The month is represented with MM in the format string, not with mm like in the examples above. mm means minutes.

Comment: I changed yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-MM-dd, cause initial version didn't work

Comment: "mm" is number of minutes :)

Comment: "yyyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

Answer (score 550):

Use [`LocalDateTime#parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)) (or [`ZonedDateTime#parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)) if the string happens to contain a time zone part) to parse a `String` in a certain pattern into a `LocalDateTime`.

```
String oldstring = "2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(oldstring, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"));
```

Then use [`LocalDateTime#format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)) (or [`ZonedDateTime#format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter))) to format a `LocalDateTime` into a `String` in a certain pattern.

```
String newstring = datetime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
System.out.println(newstring); // 2011-01-18
```

**Or**, when you're not on Java 8 yet, use [`SimpleDateFormat#parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) to parse a `String` in a certain pattern into a `Date`.

```
String oldstring = "2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(oldstring);
```

Then use [`SimpleDateFormat#format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) to format a `Date` into a `String` in a certain pattern.

```
String newstring = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
System.out.println(newstring); // 2011-01-18
```

#### See also:

- [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion/)

---

**Update**: as per your failed attempt which you added to the question after this answer was posted; the patterns are **case sensitive**. Carefully read the [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) what the individual parts stands for. So stands for example `M` for months and `m` for minutes. Also, years exist of four digits `yyyy`, not five `yyyyy`. Look closer at the code snippets I posted here above.

Comment: What if you want the date to look like "Monday 1st September 2012"?

Comment: @crm: Just click the javadoc link, figure the necessary pattern characters there and alter the pattern accordingly.

Comment: When you're not on Java 8 yet, consider using the backport, [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), and then the first examples from the answer. Or for Android below API level 26, [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Answer (score 178):

Formatting are CASE-SENSITIVE so USE MM for month not mm (this is for minute) and yyyy 
For [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you can use following cheatsheet.

```
G   Era designator  Text    AD
y   Year    Year    1996; 96
Y   Week year   Year    2009; 09
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
w   Week in year    Number  27
W   Week in month   Number  2
D   Day in year Number  189
d   Day in month    Number  10
F   Day of week in month    Number  2
E   Day name in week    Text    Tuesday; Tue
u   Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)    Number  1
a   Am/pm marker    Text    PM
H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
k   Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12
m   Minute in hour  Number  30
s   Second in minute    Number  55
S   Millisecond Number  978
z   Time zone   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z   Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
X   Time zone   ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00
```

Examples:

```
"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z"  2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
"EEE, MMM d, ''yy"  Wed, Jul 4, '01
"h:mm a"    12:08 PM
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz" 12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
"K:mm a, z" 0:08 PM, PDT
"yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa"  02001.July.04 AD 12:08 PM
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"    Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700
"yyMMddHHmmssZ" 010704120856-0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"   2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"   2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00
"YYYY-'W'ww-u"  2001-W27-3
```

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" should be "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

Comment: no if u put Z in single quote it will give Z as output but without it it will give Timezone. eg. 2014-08-14T01:24:57.236Z and from without it
2014-08-14T01:24:57.236-0530 --> I tried on jdk1.7

Comment: "yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa"  02001.July.04 AD 12:08 PM
Note extra M in month. Four not five!

Comment: if it's 4 letters or more, then the full form is used. so you can use 4 times m or even 5 times m its same

Comment: This is pretty much a Copy-Paste of the docs. No extra explanations are being provided, and there is no link to the docs where more info could be acquired if needed. -1. ([Here's the link btw](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))

Comment: This is the most satisfying answer that I have found on using date formatter on java. Thank you very much

Comment: In Android, `MMMMM` didn't work for me, but `MMMM` did.

Comment: Thanks, very nice! I needed use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX`

Answer (score 118):

The answer is of course to create a SimpleDateFormat object and use it to parse Strings to Date and to format Dates to Strings.  If you've tried SimpleDateFormat and it didn't work, then please show your code and any errors you may receive.

Addendum:  "mm" in the format String is not the same as "MM".  Use MM for months and mm for minutes. Also, yyyyy is not the same as yyyy.  e.g.,:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class FormateDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String date_s = "2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";

        // *** note that it's "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" not "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"  
        SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date date = dt.parse(date_s);

        // *** same for the format String below
        SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.println(dt1.format(date));
    }

}
```

Comment: import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class formateDate {

 /**
  * @param args
  * @throws ParseException 
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  String date_s=" 2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";
  SimpleDateFormat dt= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
  Date date=dt.parse(date_s);
  SimpleDateFormat dt1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-mm-dd");
      
  System.out.println(  dt1.format(date));
 }

}   i want out put should be "2011-01-18" but out put is 02011-00-1

Comment: Post any code you have as an addition to the original question (indented four spaces).  This way it will retain its formatting and we can then read it.

Comment: See edit to my answer above.  You're using "mm" in your format String where you should be using "MM"

Comment: `hh` will give you the hour in the range 1-12, you'll need to use `a` in addition to print/parse `AM` or `PM`. To print/parse the hour in the range 0-23, use `HH`.

Answer (score 32):

Why not simply use this

```
Date convertToDate(String receivedDate) throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = formatter.parse(receivedDate);
        return date;
    }
```

Also, this is the other way :

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String requiredDate = df.format(new Date()).toString();
```

or

```
Date requiredDate = df.format(new Date());
```

Comment: Why not use this? Because (a) it ignores the issue of time zone. Determining the date depends on the time zone. This code depends on the JVM's default time zone. So, results may vary inadvertently. And (b) because the java.util.Date and SimpleDateFormat classes are notoriously troublesome and should be avoided.

Comment: always return strin,  Date requiredDate = df.format(new Date());

Answer (score 16):

Using the `java.time` package in Java 8 and later:

```
String date = "2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";
TemporalAccessor temporal = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
    .parse(date); // use parse(date, LocalDateTime::from) to get LocalDateTime
String output = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").format(temporal);
```

Answer (score 13):

[edited to include BalusC's corrections]
The [SimpleDateFormat](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm) class should do the trick:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
try {
  Date date = format.parse("2011-01-18 00:00:00.0");
  System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `DD` stands for "day in year", not "day in month". `hh` stands for "hour in am/pm (1-12)", not "hour in day (0-23)".

Answer (score 11):

Please refer "Date and Time Patterns" here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class DateConversionExample{

  public static void main(String arg[]){

    try{

    SimpleDateFormat sourceDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

    Date date = sourceDateFormat.parse("2011-01-18 00:00:00.0");


    SimpleDateFormat targetDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println(targetDateFormat.format(date));

    }catch(ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 9):

Other answers are correct, basically you had the wrong number of "y" characters in your pattern.

### Time Zone

One more problem though… You did not address time zones. If you intended [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), then you should have said so. If not, the answers are not complete. If all you want is the date portion without the time, then no issue. But if you do further work that may involve time, then you should be specifying a time zone.

### Joda-Time

Here is the same kind of code but using the third-party open-source [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

String date_s = "2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";

org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS" );
// By the way, if your date-time string conformed strictly to ISO 8601 including a 'T' rather than a SPACE ' ', you could
// use a formatter built into Joda-Time rather than specify your own: ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecondFraction().
// Like this:
//org.joda.time.DateTime dateTimeInUTC = org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecondFraction().withZoneUTC().parseDateTime( date_s );

// Assuming the date-time string was meant to be in UTC (no time zone offset).
org.joda.time.DateTime dateTimeInUTC = formatter.withZoneUTC().parseDateTime( date_s );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInUTC: " + dateTimeInUTC );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInUTC (date only): " + org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.date().print( dateTimeInUTC ) );
System.out.println( "" ); // blank line.

// Assuming the date-time string was meant to be in Kolkata time zone (formerly known as Calcutta). Offset is +5:30 from UTC (note the half-hour).
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone kolkataTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
org.joda.time.DateTime dateTimeInKolkata = formatter.withZone( kolkataTimeZone ).parseDateTime( date_s );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInKolkata: " + dateTimeInKolkata );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInKolkata (date only): " + org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.date().print( dateTimeInKolkata ) );
// This date-time in Kolkata is a different point in the time line of the Universe than the dateTimeInUTC instance created above. The date is even different.
System.out.println( "dateTimeInKolkata adjusted to UTC: " + dateTimeInKolkata.toDateTime( org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeInUTC: 2011-01-18T00:00:00.000Z
dateTimeInUTC (date only): 2011-01-18

dateTimeInKolkata: 2011-01-18T00:00:00.000+05:30
dateTimeInKolkata (date only): 2011-01-18
dateTimeInKolkata adjusted to UTC: 2011-01-17T18:30:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 8):

```java
try
{
    String date_s = "2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";
    SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    Date tempDate=simpledateformat.parse(date_s);
    SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");           
    System.out.println("Output date is = "+outputDateFormat.format(tempDate));
} catch (ParseException ex) 
{
    System.out.println("Parse Exception");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just use:

```
Date yourDate = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(yourDate);
```

It works perfectly!

Comment: this code returns error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: @IvanFrolov may be you have a missing import, in which line you get the error?

Comment: oh, sorry - did not noticed that it's solution for Java, I've searched solution for javascript))) (btw - already found).
Thanks!

Comment: Ah okay, it's obvious now.

Answer (score 7):

```
public class SystemDateTest {

    String stringDate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SystemDateTest systemDateTest = new SystemDateTest();
        // format date into String
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        systemDateTest.setStringDate(simpleDateFormat.format(systemDateTest.getDate()));
        System.out.println(systemDateTest.getStringDate());
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return new Date();
    }

    public String getStringDate() {
        return stringDate;
    }

    public void setStringDate(String stringDate) {
        this.stringDate = stringDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some information to your answer(s) to explain your code.

Comment: there is a method name getDate() by which u can get date obj after that apply SimpleDateFormat so that you can convert date according to your format which is defined in SimpleDateFormat constructor and set in StringDate method you can make it cached

Answer (score 6):

```
   String str = "2000-12-12";
   Date dt = null;
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    try 
    {
         dt = formatter.parse(str);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, formatter.format(dt));
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try **Java 8** new `date`, more information can be found on the [Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html).

Or you can try the old one

```java
public static Date getDateFromString(String format, String dateStr) {

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return date;
}

public static String getDate(Date date, String dateFormat) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use substring()

```
String date_s = "2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";
date_s.substring(0,10);
```

If you want a space in front of the date, use

```
String date_s = " 2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";
date_s.substring(1,11);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private SimpleDateFormat dataFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if(value instanceof Date) {
        value = dataFormat.format(value);
    }
    return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

remove one y form the format provide to:

```
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-mm-dd");
```

It should be:

```
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Comment: Not exactly. You need the correct case too (no matter if you use the modern `DateTimeFormatter` or cling with the outdated `SimpleDateFormat`).

Answer (score 1):

We can convert Today's date in the format of *'JUN 12, 2020'*.

```
String.valueOf(DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date())));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Method will take Date in "MMMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:s" format and return time difference like added: 3 min ago
 *
 * @param date : date in "MMMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:s" format
 * @return : time difference
 */
private String getDurationTimeStamp(String date) {
    String timeDifference = "";

    //date formatter as per the coder need
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:s");
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
    sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    Date startDate = null;
    try {
        startDate = sdf.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        MyLog.printStack(e);
    }

    //end date will be the current system time to calculate the lapse time difference
    Date endDate = new Date();

    //get the time difference in milliseconds
    long duration = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
    long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
    long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
    long diffInDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(duration);

    if (diffInDays >= 365) {
        int year = (int) (diffInDays / 365);
        timeDifference = year + mContext.getString(R.string.year_ago);
    } else if (diffInDays >= 30) {
        int month = (int) (diffInDays / 30);
        timeDifference = month + mContext.getString(R.string.month_ago);
    }
    //if days are not enough to create year then get the days
    else if (diffInDays >= 1) {
        timeDifference = diffInDays + mContext.getString(R.string.day_ago);
    }
    //if days value<1 then get the hours
    else if (diffInHours >= 1) {
        timeDifference = diffInHours + mContext.getString(R.string.hour_ago);
    }
    //if hours value<1 then get the minutes
    else if (diffInMinutes >= 1) {
        timeDifference = diffInMinutes + mContext.getString(R.string.min_ago);
    }
    //if minutes value<1 then get the seconds
    else if (diffInSeconds >= 1) {
        timeDifference = diffInSeconds + mContext.getString(R.string.sec_ago);
    } else if (timeDifference.isEmpty()) {
        timeDifference = mContext.getString(R.string.now);
    }

    return mContext.getString(R.string.added) + " " + timeDifference;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to change 2019-12-20 10:50 AM GMT+6:00 to 2019-12-20 10:50 AM 
first of all you have to understand the date format first one date format is 
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a zzz and second one date format will be yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a

just return a string from this function like.

```
public String convertToOnlyDate(String currentDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a ");
    Date date;
    String dateString = "";
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(currentDate);
        System.out.println(date.toString()); 

        dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dateString;
}
```

This function will return your desire answer. If you want to customize more just add or remove component from the date format.

Answer (score 0):

you have some wrong:
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-mm-dd");

first :
should be
 `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");`
//yyyy 4 not 5
this display 02011, but yyyy it disply 2011

second:
change your code like this
`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`

i hope help you

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

In March 2014, [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> API supplanted the error-prone `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`. Since then it has been highly recommended to stop using the legacy API.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

### You do not need `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting

You need `DateTimeFormatter` only for parsing your string but you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to get the date in the desired format. The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and thus the `toString` implementation of `java.time` types return a string in ISO 8601 format. Your desired format is the default format of [`LocalDate#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--).

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s.S", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDate, dtfInput);
        // Alternatively,
        // LocalDateTime ldt = dtfInput.parse(strDate, LocalDateTime::from);

        LocalDate date = ldt.toLocalDate();
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-01-18
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/MxXM2D)

**Some important notes about the solution:**

1. `java.time` made it possible to call `parse` and `format` functions on the [Date-Time type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) itself, **in addition to** the traditional way (i.e. calling `parse` and `format` functions on the formatter type, which is `DateTimeFormatter` in case of `java.time` API).
2. Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score -1):

```
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Comment: This date-time class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Specifically `DateTimeFormatter` and `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`. Suggesting `SimpleDateFormat` in 2019 is poor advice.

Comment: **Incorrect** Your formatting codes here are wrong. `hh` is for hour.

Comment: Usually we expect some discussion or explanation. Stack Overflow is meant to be more than a snippet library.

Answer (score -1):

First, your year is being 0 padded because you have used 5 `y` characters, instead of 4.

Secondly, you're using a lower case `m`, whereas you want a capital `M`.

```java
String date_s = " 2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date date = dt.parse(date_s);
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(dt1.format(date));
```

Output

```
2011-01-18
```

You can also use a `String.format`, with a `%tF` modifier.
This maps to the ISO 8601 date format, which is yyyy-MM-dd.
See [Formatter (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)

```java
System.out.printf("%tF", date.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. (1) No one should use the notoriously troublesome and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` any more. IMHO helping people how to do htat is doing them an il favour. (2) `SimpleDateFormat` didn’t care whether there were 4 or 5 `y` when parsing. Even if you wanted to use that bad class, you were on the wrong track. (3) You are not covering all the issues with the original code. Older answers do that better.