# Why does my date parsing return a weird date?

Tags: java, date

Here is the code I am using:

```
String string = "08/07/2013".replace('/', '-');
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(string);
```

Why does date return: "Wen Jan 3 00:00:00 EST 14"? It is not at all the date format I told it to use.

Edit: I need this format because a database I am using requires this format.

Comment: Because the format and string doesn't match.

Comment: What is your print instruction?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot What do you mean? string is equal to "08-07-2013"

Comment: That has the days at the front

Comment: The string has format `MM-dd-yyyy`(or maybe `dd-MM-yyyy`) not `yyyy-MM-dd` as you wrote in your code.

Comment: Your String should be 2013/07/08.

Comment: @jacen.garriss Because this is an extremely simple question. Did you even read the javadoc for SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: @Kayaman I never understand the javadoc. Besides that, if this is a simple question then it is free rep for little work. what is bad about that? And it is there for the next person with the same problem.

Comment: @jacen.garriss If you never understand the javadoc, how will you ever become a programmer? And there are people with real problems who would deserve help, not lazy people who can't be bothered to use their own brains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format you use to parse the date string, does not match it. You are using `yyyy` for `08`.

Use the following format:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

and why at all are you replacing the `/` with `-`? You can build the pattern for your original string only:

```
String string = "08/07/2013"
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(string);
```

and if you want your date string in `yyyy-MM-dd` format, then you can format the `date` using [`DateFormat#format(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) method:

```
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
```

**See also:**

- [Change date format in a Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4772425/1679863)
- [SimpleDateFormat Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I can't I need the format in this format so I can pass it to a database that uses this format.

Comment: @jacen.garriss. Then you can re-format the date using the required format.

Comment: I display to the user in the format 08/07/2013 but i want to turn it into the other format for uses in the database.

Answer (score 1):

When you are specifying some Simple Date format using string e.g. "yyyy-MM-dd" , you have to provide your date in same format to get a date object eg.  "1991-07-24" .

```
String mydate = "1991/07/24";
Date formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(mydate);
```

now if you want to convert it in any other format, you can do that by FORMATTING this date object into that perticular format..

```
String dateInOtherFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(formatteddate);
```

and the output of dateInOtherFormat will be ...   24-JUL-1991 .

Answer (score 0):

Ok my sugestion is stupid but if you need this format try this

```
String[] arr = "08/07/2013".split("/");
String newString = arr[2]+"-"+arr[1]+"-"arr[0];
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(newString);
```

NOTE If your original strin is in format "MM/dd/YYYY use this:

```
String newString = arr[2]+"-"+arr[0]+"-"arr[1];
```