# IllegalArgumentException: cannot format given Object as a Date

Tags: java, date, datetime, jakarta-ee, exception

I am trying to set on context object through setter method. But i am getting an error  for the line of code below :

> IllegalArgumentException: cannot format given Object as a Date

```
contextBO.setSettlDate(
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
        .format( nppRequest.getIntrBankSettlementDt().toString())
);
```

value coming from `nppRequest.getIntrBankSettlementDt()` is `"2016-04-14"`, Can you guys please help me out here.

Comment: Debug to find the value of `nppRequest.getIntrBankSettlementDt().toString()` and then try for format it with your pattern.

Comment: The `format` method accepts a `java.util.Date`, not a `String`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the format of Date Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628059/change-the-format-of-date-java)

Answer (score 3):

(1) From the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and your input:

> nppRequest.getIntrBankSettlementDt() is "2016-04-14"

The format to be used should be:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

---

(2) Also assuming `nppRequest.getIntrBankSettlementDt()` being a `Date`, you need not convert it into a `String`.

---

And since *need in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss"*, follow (2) above as:

```
contextBO.setSettlDate(
   new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
      .format( nppRequest.getIntrBankSettlementDt())
```

Comment: But i need in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"

Comment: @Raj Updated in the answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you out

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
    contextBO.setSettlDate(dateFormat.format( nppRequest.getIntrBankSettlementDt()));
```