# Java How to read date dynamically

Tags: java, date

I have a string with six numbers: `650310`. It represents `1965 march 10` in `YYMMDD` format.

Is there any method to recognize this format to `10 march 1965`?
Currently this is my method of doing which isn't very effective.

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //date in YYMMDD

        //String x = "650310";
        String x = "161020";
        System.out.print(x.substring(4, 6)+" ");

        if (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(2, 4)) == 10) {
            System.out.print("October"+" ");
        }
        else  if (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(2, 4)) == 03) {
            System.out.print("March"+" ");
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(0, 2)) > 50) {
            String yr = "19" + x.substring(0, 2);
            System.out.println(yr);
        } else if (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(0, 2)) < 50) {
            String yr = "20" + x.substring(0, 2);
            System.out.println(yr);
        }
    }
}

output : 20 October 2016
```

Comment: use need to construct date Object  and use dateFormatter

Comment: google for "parse date in Java" and you'll get dozens of answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Java's SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyMMdd" );
Date theDate = format.parse( "650310" );
```

Now you have a Date object which you can use to display the date in other formats:

```
SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd MMMMM yyyy" );
StringBuffer output = outFormat.format( theDate );
```

Use `output.toString()` to display your newly formatted date. Good luck.

Comment: this is close, after fixing the error it gave me 20-10-2016 i want the 10 to be October

Comment: @user2822351 How about looking up the JavaDoc of  `SimpleDateFormat? You will find tons of format parameters there.

Comment: Did you try after my last edit? That one gives you the month in text. Remember, that is localized according to the JVM's locale.

Answer (score 1):

try this example

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyMMdd" );
        Date theDate = s.parse( "650310" );
        SimpleDateFormat p = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd MMMMM yyyy" );
System.out.println(p.format(theDate));
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT** 10 March 1965

Comment: I posted this method.

Comment: this however display 10 January 1965

Comment: @user2822351 make mm capital

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for date parsing. For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
try {
        System.out.println(format.parse("900310"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output: Sat Mar 10 00:00:00 MSK 1990

EDIT: if you want to parse date,try to use DateFormat to get `Date` !!!! And then you can format it in your own way. I disagree with your downvote.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
    try {
        Date parse = format.parse("900310");
        format.applyPattern("dd MMMM yyyy");
        System.out.println(format.format(parse));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

output 10/Март/1990

Comment: i doesnt want the time, i only want date mth year

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java) will help. Create a SimpleDateFormat object and use it to parse Strings to Date and to format Dates to Strings.