# Android date format conversion

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

i have value of date and time

date=2013/11/16

i want to convert this into
following format

like this

"16 November 2013,Saturday"

please help me out thanks in advance

Comment: Use the SimpleDateFormat class in java. Here's a usefull [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: visit this link it will help you http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Isn't any answer help you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use SimpleDateFormat  like this..

```
String dtStart = "2013/11/16";
SSimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy,EEEE");
try {
    date = format.parse(dtStart);
    System.out.println("Date ->" + date);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
DateFormat format = android.text.format.DateFormat.getLongDateFormat(context);
format.format(date)
```

You get `Saturday, November 16, 2013`. If you want to stick to the format you posted you can use SimpleDateFormat as suggested:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd M yyyy, E",context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy, EEEE");
String date = sdf.format(now);
Log.d("Home", date);
```

Read more on Simple Date format at [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you could use an amazing date-time lib called [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/). It makes all datetime manipulations in Java much easier.

Using JodaTime:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse("2013/11/16", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY/MM/dd"));
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMMM YYYY, EEEE");
String date = dt.toString(dtf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMdd");
            Date d;
            try {
                d = fmt.parse(st);
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            SimpleDateFormat prnt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
            String newDate=prnt.format(d)
```