# Convert date from string "yyyyddmm hh:mm:ss" to String "DD/MM/YYYY" in JAVA

Tags: java, date, datetime

Can someone help me with this conversion ?

```
String dateTime="20140505 03:23:50"
DateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy");
String date=formatter.format(dateTime);
```

I want the output to be in this format - "DD/MM/YYYY" which should be a string .

Comment: You should firstly search that question on forum I think. [LINK HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)

Comment: make sure to use lower case "d"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to do this :

```
String dateTime="20140505 03:23:50";
DateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
Date date=formatter.parse(dateTime);
formatte.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateStr = formatter.format(date);
```

First you have to convert your `String` to `Date` object using `formatter.parse(string)` based on your `String` pattern, and then you can change your `Date` to any `String` format by changing your `SimpleDateFormat` pattern.

**Note:** *`D:` day in year* and *`d:` day in month*, So use `d` instead of `D`.

You can use verity of patterns in java to format date as per your requirement. 
[image]

Comment: i'm getting applyPattern(String) is undefined for type DateFormat.

Comment: at your 2nd line `DateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy");`,  use `SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy");`, `DateFormat` is parent class of `SimpleDateFormat` and it has not have `applyPattern(String)` method.

Comment: ...and don't forget to accept the ans if this **helped** you...:)

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting with a string (rather than a `Date`), you want a string as output, and the format is that consistent then the simplest answer would just be to use substring manipulation

```
dateTime.substring(6, 8) + "/" + dateTime.substring(4, 6) + "/"
      + dateTime.substring(0, 4)
```