# How to convert string to date in us time zone format in java

Tags: java

How to convert  string to date in us time zone format in java .I am trying to convert string to date in us time zone format but it is always taking IST format

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Alaska");
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

String date="Sun, 9 Mar 2014 02:00:00 EST";

Date d = null;
try {
  d = sdf.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("date is"+d);
boolean inDs = tz.inDaylightTime(d);
System.out.println("inDs"+inDs);
```

while printing date  `Mar 09 12:30:00 IST 2014`

Comment: Your code throws `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun, 9 Mar 2014 02:00:00 EST"`.

Comment: See the out put properly and then post.....

Comment: @Nitul can you tell what is problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)

Comment: @LutzHorn try with `Locale.ENGLISH` as 2nd paremeter to sdf, since if you are in a European locale then "Sun" is not valid...

Comment: A `Date` object has no concept of a time zone. What you are seeing is the default `toString()` output for a `Date`, which just outputs the date using your local time zone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 0):

Use Calendar instead of Date. Anyways the below solution of converting a date to Calendar and back to Date is not efficient. If you can get the day, month, year etc. seperately, its better to use `cal.set()`

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Alaska");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

    String date = "Sun, 9 Mar 2014 02:00:00 EST";

    Date d = null;
    try {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
        cal.setTimeZone(tz);
        System.out.println("date is " + cal.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```