# SimpleDateFormat function parse(String s) gives wrong date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

As an input I have Date object(for example, exDate=Fri Aug 01 00:00:00 EEST 2014) that must be formated. After the parsing of the date, I get wrong date.

```
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd-MMM-YYYY hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS aa", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String dateStart = sdf.format(exDate);
            Date dateF = sdf.parse(dateStart);
```

dateStart will be equal to

```
01-Aug-2014 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

and the resut, dateF will be equal to

```
Sun Dec 29 00:00:00 EET 2013
```

So, after the parsing of a string with date, the result is wrong. 
Maybe, somebody know the source of the problem? Or another way to format date in another `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java

Comment: `YYYY` doesn't mean what you think it does. Try `yyyy`, and read the docs to see what `YYYY` really means.

Comment: Additionally, in future it would help if you'd provide a short but *complete* program that we could just copy, compile, run.

Comment: There are only 1000 milliseconds in a second. `.SSS`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - but there are a lot more nanoseconds.  `S` x 9 would imply nanoseconds.

Comment: It's curious -- why are you formatting a date and then turning around and parsing the formatted value?  What do you expect that to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you to everybody. Yes, the problem was so small...=(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the YYYY [which means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24423756/2188186):

```
 Y   Week year;
```

The actual year, which is what you are looking for would be `yyyy`.

I really recommend that you go in the link above to see the [full list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24423756/2188186).

You should also replace the milliseconds to `.SSS` as you can't get more precise than that.

Comment: Or go to the [ultimate authority](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).  (Though I don't know if SDF honors all those variations.)