# Convert String " yyyy-MM-dd" to "E, MMM d"

Tags: java, android, date

I'm trying to convert a String coming as "2014-11-04" from a Json Object, to "Tue,Nov 4" (I think it's "E, MMM d") but without sucess so far.

Here is the code of my last try:

```
private String convertDateString(String date) {

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");

        String convertedDate = formatter.format(date);


        return convertedDate;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4772425/642706) and many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try as follows

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date=formatter.parse("2014-11-04");
                             formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

You needs to convert `String` to `Date` first, Since current `String` is not other format.

Follow [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), next time it will help you.

Comment: Oh yes indeed, thats what was missing in my logic. Thx!!

Answer (score 3):

```
private static String convertDateString(String date) {

        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");

        String convertedDate = null;
        try {
            convertedDate = formatter.format(f.parse(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertedDate;
    }
```

Input  `System.out.print(convertDateString("1990-10-11"));`

Output `Thu, Oct 11`

Answer (score 1):

To change date from one format to another,first convert original formatted `String` to `date` and then format it to target format.
try this

```
private String convertDateString(String dateInString) {
    SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");
    Date date = originalFormat.parse(dateInString);
    return targetFormat.format(date);
}
```