# Java new date() with milliseconds

Tags: java

i got this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date data = new Date();
```

how can be the "data" variable be in the "sdfDate" format?

i need about this output (it must be the current time):

```
2014-11-10 17:48:20.128
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
sdfDate.format(data);
```

This is the correct way to use your dateformatter to format a given date.

Ex.

```
System.out.println("Date: " + sdfDate.format(data));
```

Comment: i need a Date type not a string, how i can i do? convert it later or is there a better way?

Comment: You have a date type already data is the date type.  You can format that date in whatever valid way by using SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking then `Date data = new Date();` this is your Date type.

Comment: @RudiDudi A `Date` object has no concept of what format it's supposed to be in. You leave it as is and format it, receiving a string,  when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `format` function on `sdfDate`. `SimpleDateFormat` [inherits it from `DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-).

```
String result = sdfDate.format(data);
```

Comment: i need a Date type not a string, how i can i do? convert it later or is there a better way?