# Date is showed with unexpected value in html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, date

I used Bootstrap datepicker to get date from the user. I stored that value in database. 
But when i render this date in html, it showed unexpected value with the date !

I give the screen shot of the result.

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Comment: Perhaps an earlier question will help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

How have you stored the date in the database?

Make sure you used DATETIME and not VARCHAR

Also how did you get the date from the database?

I would use:

```
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ColumnName, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS Date FROM Table";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
$date = $result->fetch_object()->Date;
```

Comment: In Java please .........

Comment: @Romeo You didn't specified a language. His answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: $query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ColumnName, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS Date FROM Table";
Will this work in java ?

Comment: Sure that is SQL code which will work in both java and php

Comment: Only the handling of this query is different

Comment: After picking date by datepicker... i see it by console.log 
It shows the same with unexpected value. that means problem is in datepicker not in db.

Comment: In that case I recommend trying this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java