# preventing the use of SimpleDateFormatter twice

Tags: java, date

I had a `String` in this form, `EEE, dd MMM yy hh:mm:ss Z` and I wanted to convert it into the `Date` object so i did this,

```
SimpleDateFormat fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yy hh:mm:ss Z",Locale.getDefault());
```

then I created the instance field of type `Date`

`Date toDate = null;`

and parse my `String` date and store it into `toDate`

`toDate = fDate.parse(stringDate);`

Now the date is stored in `toDate` variable in this form,

`Tue Jan 20 07:33:06 GMT+05:30 2015`

but this is not what i wanted.
I wanted my final `Date` object in this form,

`Tue Jan 20, 2015`

So, in order to achieve this, I created the new `Calendar` object and set its time to `toDate`,

```
Calendar s = Calendar.getInstance();
s.setTime(toDate);
```

then I create a new `String` and store `Day of Week`, `Month` `Day of Month` and `year` to get this format `Tue Jan 20, 2015`.

```
String newDate = s.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,0,Locale.getDefault()) + " "
+ s.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, 0, Locale.getDefault())
+ " " + s.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + ","
+ s.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Now, my new string `newDate` has a date in this form `Tue Jan 20, 2015` and the problem is it is a `String` object and not a `Date` object, and in order to convert it to `Date` object I have to use the `SimpleDateFormatter` again.

But this is a lot of work because in order to convert `String` of this form, `EEE, dd MMM yy hh:mm:ss Z` into the `Date` object of this form, `Tue Jan 20, 2015`, I am first using `SimpleDateFormatter` then I am parsing it in a `Date` object, then I extract my desire fields from that `Date` object using `Calendar` and store in a `String`, and then convert that `String` back to the `Date` object.

Is there any easier way to achieve this ? i.e, converting this `String` `EEE, dd MMM yy hh:mm:ss Z` directly into this format `Tue Jan 20, 2015` of type `Date` without using `SimpleDateFormatter` twice ?

Comment: A `Date` does not have a format. A `Date` is a temporal concept. A _format_ is something you apply to understand or express that concept.

Comment: so you mean a `Date` object can never equal to any custom format ? and it will always equal to the complete date including time, day, year, second, locale etc ?

Comment: A `Date` represents a timestamp. The day, year, second, etc. is human readable information. To get that information you need to `format` the `Date`. It's not part of the `Date`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. You would find hundreds of Questions and Answers on this topic.

Comment: @BasilBourque, actually my question is different from what is suggested as duplicate...because I am already doing what is posted as an answer in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java..this is non-sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Java Date library is notoriously bad (which is pretty much why everyone uses the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, and why Oracle released the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) with Java 8 (see [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html)), there are a couple things to be aware of:

1. ALL java.util.Date represents is the number of milliseconds since [midnight, Jan 1, 1970 in UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). In other words, java.util.Date is really just a small wrapper around a `long` value.
2. Thus, java.util.Date does NOT store any kind of formatting info. Date.toString() just always produces a String in a human readable "debug" format.
3. To answer your question, no, there is really not a way to prevent the use of SimpleDateFormatter twice, but I don't see why you would want to avoid this, besides that it seems like you are misunderstanding the concepts of what a Date represents. If you have a java.lang.String and want to convert it to a java.util.Date, you use DateFormat.parse(), and if you have a java.util.Date and want to convert it to a java.lang.String, you use DateFormat.format().