# Setting date into "dd"-"mm"-"yy" format from "dd"-"mm"-"yyyy" in java

Tags: java, date, split

I have a date in the format dd-mm-yyyy format(inside my db).I need to convert it to dd-mm-yy format.I retrieved date from db and stored it inside a string.

```
String date=doc.getString("date");

for example: 05-19-1990

to
    05-19-90.
```

That 1990 is not fully needed only 90 is needed.Using split() in java  i tried some thing but it wont helps me.Can anyone please help.Any help will be highly appreciated.......

Comment: Use two `SimpleDateFormat`s, one to parse it, one to format it...

Comment: That's mm-dd-yy(yy), not dd-mm-yy(yy). Unless, of course, you use some weird calendar with 20 months.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
 try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy");
        Date d = sdf.parse("05-19-1990");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for that issue:

```
DateFormat df = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
DateFormat df1 = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
df1.format(df.parse(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two `SimpleDateFormat`s, one to parse it, one to format it..

```
SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date inDate = in.parse(date); // 05-19-1990
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy");
String newDate = out.format(inDate);
```

or

```
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
String newDate = out.format(inDate);
```

If you really want `19-05-90` as per the title of your question ;)

Check [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yy");
String formattedDate2 = df2.format(theDate);
```