# How can I generate date object from string in format "23-Jan-2015" in java and javascript

Tags: java, javascript

I need some help. I need to create a new date object in mm/dd/yyyy format from a string of format 24-Mar-2015.

Comment: `Date` objects don't "know" about a format. You take a `Date` object and perform whatever formatting you want on it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
String src = "24-Mar-2015";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy").parse(src);
String dst = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

In **JavaScript**

```
function getFormattedDate(date) {
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
      month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
      var day = date.getDate().toString();
      day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
      return year + '/' + month + '/' + day;
    }
    alert(getFormattedDate(new Date(2015,3,24))); // 2015/03/24
```

Answer (score 1):

The Date(String) constructor can be used to create date object from String, which can then be formatted by SimpleDateFormat.

```
  String date = "24-Mar-2015";
 System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(new Date(date)));
```

*To print month in full use SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy") instead.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
var myDate = new Date('2015/01/23');
myDate.toString(); // "Fri Jan 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)"
```