# How to get custom Date format using Java

Tags: java

I'm totally new to Java . I want to print date format like this `December 03, 2015`. 
Help me  How to frame Java expression to print this Date format `December 03, 2015`

Thanks,

Comment: Look for SimpleDateFormat

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)

Comment: Please **search StackOverflow** before posting. This topic has been addressed hundreds and hundreds of times already.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to generate custom date formats, for example...

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date()));
```

which outputs

```
December 09, 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()));

    }
}
```

for more info check this link:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    printFormattedDate(new Date());
}

public static void printFormattedDate(Date date){
    String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
    "Octorber", "November", "December"};
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println(months[month] + " " + day + ", "+ year  );
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the object of Date class like this:

```
 import java.util.Date;

    public class DateDemo {

       public static void main(String args[]) {
           // Instantiate a Date object
           Date date = new Date();

           // display formatted date
           System.out.printf("%s %tB %<te, %<tY", 
                             "Due date:", date);
       }
```

This would produce the following result:

```
Due date: February 09, 2004
```

Answer (score -2):

In Java there is a really awesome print out function with formatting abilities. It is called Java Printf. There are many different ways to format the output so I highly suggest you research Java Printf, However, for your example, the Printf would be as follows:

```
System.out.printf("%s %02d, %d","December" ,3,2015);
```

Or a more abstract version that could be used in a method:

```
 public void printDate(String month, int day, int year){
   System.out.printf("%s %02d, %d",MonthName , Day , Year);
 }
```