# How do I change the display of date of birth in java?

Tags: java, println, date

In my Java code, date of birth is retrieved from a database in the format `1999-04-30`. How can I `out.println` this in a different format? Like this: `30/04/1999`

Comment: `DateFormat` or if you specific date format you want `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate. [That Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java) is about a String representation of a date-time while this Question is about (a) a date-only value which means the use of date-only classes `java.sql.Date` and `java.time.LocalDate`, and (b) a database value rather than a mere String representation, or so we can presume.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yea, it still hasn't worked out.

Comment: @html The [Answer by Andreas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34649135/642706) is correct. Focus on the 2nd part as java.time is a *huge* improvement over the old date-time classes. Edit your Question to expound on the part that is not clear, or comment on his Answer. He is calling getDate on the ResultSet to get a java.sql.Date object (notice the `.sql.`), then calls `toLocalDate` to convert from java.sql to java.time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, the date is retrieved as a [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), which does not have a specific form.

To format such a date value, use:

```
java.sql.Date birthdate = resultSet.getDate("Birthdate");

SimpleDateFormat dateFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String text = dateFmt.format(birthdate);
```

Or, in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (Java 8 and later):

```
java.time.LocalDate birthdate = resultSet.getDate("Birthdate").toLocalDate();

DateTimeFormatter dateFmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
String text = birthdate.format(dateFmt);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can format date as follows,

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
String DateToStr = format.format(yourDataBaseDate);    
format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateToStr = format.format(yourDataBaseDate);
System.out.println(DateToStr);
```

This is sample date format for your 
question.