# Convert the time stamps into long value

Tags: android, simpledateformat, datetime-conversion

I would like to convert this time stamps to Long value.

```
2016-07-13T21:11:45+00:00
```

I still don't know what the format of above time stamp, like `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa` to use with the `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: do u want to convert MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format time to long?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string/24423756#24423756

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this code to**

```
   String timeStr = "2016-11-01T09:45:00.000+02:00";
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
   Date dateObj= sdf.parse(timeStr);
   System.out.println(dateObj.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss and you can convert it to long by:

```
public static long convertDateToMilliseconds(String fromFormat, String sourceDate) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdfFrom = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
        //SimpleDateFormat sdfTo = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);

        Date date = sdfFrom.parse(sourceDate);
        //String convertedDate = sdfTo.format(date);

        return date.getTime();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string/24423756#24423756) to find in which formate to create Simple date formater then create date object with that date formater.  Then you can get time in millis like below

```
long millisecond = beginupd.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) almost states this in its examples. For that you can use

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
```

Comment: ```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'```

Comment: @SonNguyenThanh the documentation is really reliable sometimes. I found that people use `ZZZZZ` instead of `XXX` to read the timezones. Maybe this works like intended.