# Value for AM/PM in SimpleDateFormat method

Tags: java

I want to use `SimpleFormatMethod` for date time like - `09/20/2016 10:10:10 PM`. As I found in google, it could be like -

`SimpleDateFormat sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS ?");`

but what should in place of `?` which stands for AM/PM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change date format in a Java string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string)

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

`SimpleDateFormat sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS aaa");`

Answer (score 0):

As per [SimpleDateFormat docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html): "Am/pm marker" is letter `a`.

So in your case, you want:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS a");
```

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) "Am/pm marker" is letter `a`.
You can follow Documentation for more help

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS aaa");
```