# Java convert Date in string to Date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

how to convert this string "2016-10-08T01:00:00-07:00" to date object in Java?
I want to know what is string format to use with SimpleDateFormat.

I have try

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

try {
  Date date = format.parse("2016-10-08T01:00:00-07:00");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your format from `Z` to `X` will work . Detail is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
```

Comment: It works perfectly, Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, but if you are using java 8, you should try with `LocalDate`,`LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime` :)

Answer (score 0):

`Date date = format.parse("2016-10-08T01:00:00-07:00");`

should be

`Date date = format.parse("2016-10-08T01:00:00-0700");`

The time zone should not have a colon delimiting hours and minutes.

Comment: This date I get it from google.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");

Best solution to refer @ [Change date format in a Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string)