# how to get date timestamp value from excel sheet using Java Excel library

Tags: java, excel, date, datetime, jxl

I am using Java Excel API (jxl library) for reading data present in excel file in Java

In my input excel file, I have a column which contains date. Date can be in any format like say `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` or `yy/mm/dd` etc. 
While reading the file, I can get date in any format.

Right now the issue I am facing is, Date  in the input excel file is `9/15/2017  12:30:00 PM`, but when I am reading the date column value using `getDate()` function of Java Excel API (jxl library), it is returning me modified timestamp value in the i.e. `Fri Sep 15 18:00:00 IST 2017`

```
Date inputdate = ((DateCell) icell).getDate();
```

`((DateCell) icell).getDate()` returns `Fri Sep 15 18:00:00 IST 2017`.
I want the same date time value that is present in the excel file.

How should I get the same date time value that is present in the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Once you read the `Date` frow excel using `getdDate()` you need to format the date using a Formatter. Please refer the following URL to understand how to format Date 
[Change date format in a Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string)

Comment: there is not single format used. User can provide date in any format in the excel sheet. SO with the given date, how can I know its format? I would request to share a example relevant to my question. The provided link does fit in my scenario.

Comment: try this and see what is the value you are getting cell.getCellFormat().getFormat().getFormatString();