# Time String to time representation Java

Tags: java

I have a string like this `210115` I want to represent it as `21:01:15` any ideas?.
I tried using Gregorian calendar but it adds date to it which I don't want

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
Date date = new Date();
try{
 date = sdf.parse("210115");
}
 catch(Exception e){
}

Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
System.out.print(calendar.getTime());
```

Output is `Thu Jan 01 21:01:15 UTC 1970` but what I want is just `21:01:15`

Thanks.

Comment: There is no time  without Date as a date object

Comment: The question is why even convert to date, if you simply want a string?

Just do:
    String s = "210115";
    String output = s.substring(0,2) + ":" + s.substring(2,2) + ":" + s.substring(4,2);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change date format in a Java string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string)

Comment: Use `java.time.LocalTime` instead of class `java.util.Date`. Class `Date` is not suitable for holding only a time without a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To output a formatted date, you use another `SimpleDateFormat` object with a pattern with the format you want.

In this case, it sounds like you might want to use something like

`SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println( outputFormat.format(date) );`

Answer (score 2):

So what you want is just a time, without time zone. I would recommend using the `LocalTime` class, which is exactly that, instead of the `Date` class.

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("210115", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss"));
```

Comment: I was just about to answer this myself. Also, the `toString()` implementation seems to guarantee the _HH:mm:ss_ output.

Comment: @Magnilex yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

If u r getting the date string in "**210115**" this format and you want it in "**21:01:15**" format then why are you using date format.
Simply do string operation as:

```
  String time="210115";
        String newtime=time.substring(0,2)+":"+time.substring(2,4)+":"+time.substring(4,6);
        System.out.println(newtime);
```

you will get the required format.**21:01:15**