# Java parse Date from string

Tags: java, date

I've a problem with date. I've a date as string in format:  "2017-05-10 16:30"
I'd like to convert it to date looking the same as I wrote before.
Please help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, have you investigated [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)?  Second of all, that's not how date/time objects work. Date/time objects are containers for the amount of time which has passed from a given point in time, they don't carry any formatting of their own, that's what things like [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) are for, they take a date/time` object and generate text representation based on the supplied format

Comment: [Change date format in a Java string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string/4772461#4772461) may also help

Comment: The simple trick is to use the same `DateTimeFormatter` for converting both ways. It will convert your `String` to a `LocalDateTime` and your `LocalDateTime` to a `String` looking the same.

Answer (score 0):

A simple search in google or stackoverflow might lead to answer but here you go.

**Pre Java 8**

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse("2017-05-10 16:30");
```

**Java 8**

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-05-10 16:30", dtf);
```

Comment: *"A simple search in google or stackoverflow"* - Then I'd suggest you vote to close the question as a duplicate to encourage the OP to actual do that next time - I'd also suggest that in this day and age, we should be recommending `DateTimeFormatter` over the now defunct `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 0):

You can use LocalDateTime.parse to create a LocalDateTime object, but the second part of your question didn't really make sense.  The date object itself doesn't have a format, so it can't "look like" anything.  You decide what format to adopt when you convert it back to a string.