# How to convert datetime in jmeter using beanshell sampler

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have timestamp for one of my http sampler in following format

```
Tue Nov 07 10:28:10 PST 2017
```

and i need to convert it to in following format

```
11/07/2017 10:28:10
```

i tried different approaches but don't know what am i doing wrong.Can anyone help me on that.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very similar to [how you'd do it in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string).

Here's an example:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

String string = "Tue Nov 07 10:28:10 PST 2017";

// Original format to convert from
DateFormat formatFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

// Target format to convert to
DateFormat formatTo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

// Parse original string, using original format
Date date = formatFrom.parse(string);

// Convert to a target format
String result = formatTo.format(date);

// Just to show the output, not really necessary
log.info(result);
```

One catch: since target format omits the zone, local zone of the computer will be used. So for example original time `10:28:10 PST` will be converted to `10:28:10` for computer in PST zone, but for computer in EST zone it will be converted to `13:28:10`

Comment: Thanks Kiril but i used a SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 1):

I heard [Groovy is the new black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so given:

1. [Date](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html) class in Groovy SDK has [format()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format(java.lang.String)) and [parse()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.TimeZone)) methods
2. It is recommended to use [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language since JMeter 3.1](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

you can get the date converted in a single line of Groovy code like:

```
Date.parse("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", 'Tue Nov 07 10:28:10 PST 2017').format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('PST'))
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Convert Date]