# Date conversion using Java and Oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I want to convert  "`yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'`" date format to  "`yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss`" in java.

i.e. i have a date like "`22-11-2017 23:42:09:0`" and i want to convert it into "`22-Nov-2017 23:42:09`".

Comment: Hey Buddy, Please read about [how to format dates in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string), then try to implement something for your problem. if after that you face some problem then post that.

Comment: @MT0 my bad, I used my spacebar instead of the dash. Next time, I will pay more attention. Thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

If so urgent,

```
String newValue = oldValue.substring(0, oldValue.lastIndexOf(":"));
```

would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use to_date() function in oracle sql. You can also get the output of the query by doing :

```
select to_date(#your format#)
from dual
```