# Formatting a String date into a different format in Java

Tags: java, android, string, date, date-format

I am trying to format a JSON which has a `date` key in the format:

> date: "2017-05-23T06:25:50"

My current attempt is the following:

```
private String formatDate(String date) {
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/yyyy");
  String formattedDate = "";

  try {
    formattedDate = format.format(format.parse(String.valueOf(date)));
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return formattedDate;
}
```

But in this occasion, the result isn't shown in my app, the `TextView` is invisible and I couldn't log anything.

I really tried other solutions, but no success for me. I don't know if it's because the incoming value is a string.

Comment: Are you seeing any exception? If so, please post the stacktrace in your question.

Comment: I recommend `LocalDateTime.parse(date).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu"))`. Use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to use this on Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change date format in a Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string). Use your search engine to find many more similar questions and answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this code to format your `2017-05-23T06:25:50'

```
String strDate = "2017-05-23T06:25:50";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date convertedDate = new Date();
try {
    convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
    SimpleDateFormat sdfnewformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
    String finalDateString = sdfnewformat.format(convertedDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The converted `finalDateString` set to your `textView`

Comment: Ah, so it was necessary two `SimpleDateFormat`. It worked for. But what a mess just for a simple format. Java.

Comment: Not a mess Read [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Can’t resist, please excuse: The `SimpleDateFormat` class *is* a mess. In 2017 no one should struggle with one. Let alone two. The constructive suggestion? [JSR-310, the modern Java date and time API also known as `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you.

```
String oldstring= "2017-05-23T06:25:50.0";
Date datee = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(oldstring);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me :

```
 public static String getNewsDetailsDateTime(String dateTime) {
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = format.parse(dateTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String strPublishDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy h:mm a").format(date);
    return strPublishDateTime;
}
```

**Out put format was : Dec 20 , 2017 2.30 pm.**

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu");

private static String formatDate(String date) {
    return LocalDateTime.parse(date).format(DATE_FORMATTER);
}
```

Now `formatDate("2017-05-23T06:25:50")` returns the desired string of `05/23/2017`.

### java.time

In 2017 I see no reason why you should struggle with the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API also known as JSR-310, is so much nicer to work with.

Often when converting from one date-time format to another you need two formatters, one for parsing the input format and one for formatting into the output format. Not here. This is because your string like `2017-05-23T06:25:50` is in the ISO 8601 format, the standard that the modern classes parse as their default, that is, without an explicit formatter. So we only need one formatter, for formatting.

### What went wrong in your code

When I run your code, I get a `ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-05-23T06:25:50"`. If you didn’t notice the exception already, then you have a serious flaw in your project setup that hides vital information about errors from you. Please fix first thing.

A `ParseException` has a method `getErrorOffset` (a bit overlooked), which in this case returns 4. Offset 4 in your string is where the first hyphen is. So when parsing in the format `MM/DD/yyyy`, your `SimpleDateFormat` accepted 2017 as a month (funny, isn’t it?), then expected a slash and got a hyphen instead, and therefore threw the exception.

You’ve got another error in your format pattern string: Uppercase `DD` is for day-of-year (143 in this example). Lowercase `dd` should be used for day-of-month.

### Question: Can I use `java.time` on Android?

Yes you can. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310).
- **On Android**, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where the modern date and time API was first described.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function :

```
 private String convertDate(String dt) {

            //String date="2017-05-23T06:25:50";

            try {
                SimpleDateFormat spf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"); //date format in which your current string is
                Date newDate = null;
                newDate = spf.parse(dt);
                spf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/yyyy"); //date format in which you want to convert
                dt = spf.format(newDate);
                System.out.println(dt);

                Log.e("FRM_DT", dt);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return dt;

        }
```

Comment: Wrong answer. Desired string: 05/23/2017. I got 05/143/2017.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String output = sdf1.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: Thaks for wanting to contribute. Please don’t try this. It’s better to stay far away from the notoriously troublesome and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class and friends. Furthermore in case of parse error, this will give you today^s date, which is probably not what you want and which you may only discover long after your app has been deployed.