# How to find date in a format like 27-mar-2018 in Android

Tags: android, date, format, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to get current date from system in a format like 27-mar-2018 in Android Application. I have written some for this but it is not working as it is returning date like "27-012-2018". I have tried like dd-mon-yyyy also but it is throwing error saying this format is not supported. What is the correct pattern i should use to get current date in desirable format.

Thanks in advance!

My Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RelativeLayout rldj;
RelativeLayout rlh;
RelativeLayout rlau;
RelativeLayout rldb;
RelativeLayout rlht;
RelativeLayout rlth;
RelativeLayout rltoi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rldj = findViewById(R.id.rldj);
    rlh = findViewById(R.id.rlh);
    rlau = findViewById(R.id.rlau);
    rldb = findViewById(R.id.rldb);
    rlht = findViewById(R.id.rlht);
    rlth = findViewById(R.id.rlth);
    rltoi = findViewById(R.id.rltoi);


    rlh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getDate(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
private String getDate() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change date format in a Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string)

Comment: And there is it is throwing error instead of not throwing in the question.. a typing mistake

Comment: Where are you passing the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dd-MMM-2018 worked for me but it still not returning date as i wanted it is returning like 27-Mar-2018 and I wanted it as 27-mar-2018.
I have made some changes based on your suggestions and now I am getting it perfectly(27-mar-2018).
Thankyou all for your help.
Here is the updated code:

```
private String getDate() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date).toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will provide exactly what you want

```
private String getDate() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date).toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks it worked for me but not as I wanted it is returning 27-Mar-2018 and I wanted 27-mar-2018

Comment: It should return exactly 27-mar-2018 . Just copy the code and paste to your editor

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `dd-mmm-yyyy` use `dd-MMM-yyyy`
And Replace `dateFormat.format(date)` to `dateFormat.format(date).toUpperCase()`

Comment: will it not return date as 27-MAR-2018?

Comment: And there is it is throwing error instead of not throwing in the question.. a typing mistake

Comment: Now its return 27-MAR-2017..Please check my code again.

Answer (score 1):

make change to date format change below method...

```
private String getDate() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks it worked for me but not as I wanted it is returning 27-Mar-2018 and I wanted 27-mar-2018

Comment: used this getDate().toLowerCase()

Answer (score 1):

use below method

```
private String getDate()
{


    android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
   return (String) df.format("yyyy-MMM-dd", new java.util.Date());


}
```

Answer (score 1):

For date converting you can use below code :

```
 public static String dateFormat(String dateStr) {
            String inputFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
            String outputFormat="dd MMM yyyy"
            String finalDate = "";
            SimpleDateFormat inputSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat);
            SimpleDateFormat outputSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat);
            try {
                Date date = inputSDF.parse(dateStr);
                finalDate = outputSDF.format(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.v("ffiinalDDateeEE", "finalDate: " + finalDate);


            return finalDate;
        }
```