# How to convert SQL datetime stamp to human readable time?

Tags: java, android, sql

I have a datetime stamp from the server in the form of 2017-12-27 03:31:31.243 and would like to extract the time part for display as say 3:31 am. The actual date aspect is irrelevant for my current requirements.

I realize that the Date class has been deprecated and I know how to format the date into human readable form but have not been able to figure out extracting only the time.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change date format in a Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string)

Comment: @JeffColeman I am only trying to retrieve the time though, and without referencing the Date class because that has become deprecated and would rather not. I figured it out regardless. Will post solution below

Answer (score 3):

I found this to do the trick!

```
String dateStamp = "2017-12-27 03:31:31.243";
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(dateStamp);
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
String formattedTime = fmt.format(timestamp);
return formattedTime;
```

output:

```
03:31 AM
```