# Convert days from epoch to date

Tags: java, epoch

I want to convert number of days since epoch to a date. Let's say I have the following `Timestamp in days: 17749` then it should be converted to `Monday Aug 06 2018`.

I am trying using the following code:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("D").parse(String.valueOf("17749"));
System.out.println(date);
```

But I am getting `Sun Aug 05 00:00:00 PKT 2018`. The date is one day earlier than what it should be and how can I convert it to yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change date format in a Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the latest API `java.time` you may use :

- the static method [`ofEpochDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofEpochDay-long-):

  ```
  LocalDate d = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(17749);
  System.out.println(d);                       // 2018-08-06
  ```
- the static constant [`EPOCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#EPOCH) :

  ```
  LocalDate.EPOCH.plusDays(17749);
  ```

---

Then for the output, it's only `String`, so you can use built-in formatter or create yours : [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Answer (score 2):

`D` in a [`SimpleDateFormat` pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is the day of the **year**, not days since The Epoch.

The simplest thing is probably to multiply by the number of milliseconds in a day (86400000 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) and use `new Date(milliseconds)`:

```
long days = 17749;
Date d = new Date(days * 86400000L);
```

The old `java.util.Date` is a failed API, though. You might look at `java.time.LocalDate` (or one of the other `java.time` classes), for instance, which has [`plusDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays-long-) and a handy [`EPOCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#EPOCH) static:

```
// ACTUALLY, THERE'S A BETTER WAY THAN THIS, SEE LINK AFTER CODE BLOCK
long days = 17749;
LocalDate d = LocalDate.EPOCH.plusDays(days);
```

(Ah, I missed [`ofEpochDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofEpochDay-long-), see [azro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51709180/157247).)

Comment: We should stop teaching to use old Date, and better use new time API.

Comment: @azro - Yes, it is better to use the new API. But since the OP is using `Date`, that's what I used.

Comment: They all says 'date' as it's the common word, but mostly they just don't know that Date is outdated and that a new API exists

Comment: @azro - Note the code sample in the question, which uses `Date`, specifically. I did add a note about `java.time`, though.