# Split DateTime into Combination of String and Date in Java

Tags: java, api, csv

I hit API that will return date in datetime type. The example of the return is "1994-12-03T12:00:00" and I want to modify the return become "Pca19941203". The return will be apply in csv file. I do the modification in Java. Is there some ways to do that ?

Comment: Convert the `String` value to a `LocalDateTime` object and format as you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8+ ***(Recommended)***:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

```
LocalDateTime.parse("1994-12-03T12:00:00")
             .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'Pca'uuuuMMdd"))
```

Joda-Time:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
```

```
LocalDateTime.parse("1994-12-03T12:00:00")
             .toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("'Pca'yyyyMMdd"))
```

Old Java API:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

```
new SimpleDateFormat("'Pca'yyyyMMdd").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                                     .parse("1994-12-03T12:00:00"))
```

*Output (from all 3)*

```
Pca19941203
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works for me. I use the Java 8+ solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can to do the next

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication2;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class as {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long tmp = castDateToString(new Date());

        System.out.println(tmp);
        //Devolver al servicio
        System.out.println(returnServiceFormat(tmp, "yyyy/MM/dd"));
    }

    public static long castDateToString(Date system) {
        return system.getTime();
    }

    public static String returnServiceFormat(long date, String format) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(date);
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        return String.valueOf(df.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }
}
```

The result was

> run: 1579226334699 2020/01/16 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: You have an example to understand what is the correct?

Comment: See the *Java8+* section if the answer by Andreas. That's how I recommend doing. Also see [the top voted answer to the link original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4772461/5772882) and the *Java 8 update* section of [the accpeted answer to the other linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/5772882).