# Change order of some items in a string

Tags: string, search, arraylist, replace

In my Java code (Android Studio) I have an ArrayList() dynamically created (the size of the ArrayList is not fixed). Something like:

[Name, January 2, 2020, 9:00 a.m. – 11:00 p.m., Name, Name, February 3, 2020, 9:00 a.m. – 11:00 p.m., name, Name, August 4, 2020, 9:00 a.m. – 11:00 p.m., Name, Name]

now, is it possible to search only for dates (so recognize which are dates) and then substitute in another format?

I would like, for example, Jan 2, 2020 -> 01/02/20.

My idea is scroll the ArrayList, filter the items with a switch case and then do "something" in the specific date data, but still no idea how and maybe switch case cannot search for partial matches, I'm afraid.
Like,

switch (arraytest) {

```
                case "January":
                case "February":
                case "March":
                case "April":
                case "May":
                case "June":
                case "July":
                case "August":
                case "September":
                case "October":
                case "November":
                case "December":

                    arraytest = arraytest.something...

                    break;
            }
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I got what exactly you are trying to do, but you can [convert the date string into date type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion) then [reformate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string/4772461) it as you wish.
I hope that useful.

Comment: Substantially, I have an ArrayList with several strings. Some of these strings are in the format "Month Day, Year", others are name. I would like to find only the items with "Month Day, Year" and then convert all of them from this format to MM/DD/YY.

Comment: Do you know the order of it?

Comment: Or can you stor them on objects? Then you can just object.date for ex