# How to add Firebase Timestamp when adding an object of a data class to the Firestore in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

Following is the sample of my data class to add product details to the `Firestore`, I wanted to add `Firebase` timestamp to know when the item was added. Even though I do not know how to do it, I tried to like the following but I am getting an error.

Note: I know how to add Timestamp to `Firestore` and I have done that using `"timestamp" to FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` when adding a `Hashmap`. I am having trouble when it's part of an object of my data class.

```
    @Parcelize
data class Product(
    val user_id: String = "",
    val mrp: String= "0.00",
    val price: String = "0.00",
    val description: String = "",
    val stock_quantity: String = "",
    val image: String = "",
    val product_added_date: FieldValue? = null,
) : Parcelable
```

The object of the product to add to `Firestore`.

```
val product = Product(
        FirestoreClass().getCurrentUserID(),
        et_product_mrp.text.toString(),
        et_product_price.text.toString(),
        et_product_description.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' },
        et_product_quantity.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' },
        mProductImageURL!!,,
        et_product_delivery_charge.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' },
        imageURL.size,
        FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    )
```

Comment: Any help on this, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add a Timestamp type property using an object of `Product` class, please define the field in the class to be of type [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and use the annotation as below:

```
@ServerTimestamp
var product_added_date: Date? = null,
```

When you create an object of the `Product` class, there is no need to set the date. You don't have to pass anything to the constructor. Firebase servers will read your `product_added_date` field, as it is a ServerTimestamp (see the annotation), and it will populate that field with the server Timestamp accordingly.

Otherwise, create a Map and put:

```
"product_added_date" to FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Comment: Awesome, well explained. it did great. I used it to add the timestamp and also displayed it back in my app. Just curious if I can get it back in a custom format? Suppose I want to show it as dd/mm/yy. Thanks.

Comment: Since it's a Java Date type property you can [format it as you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string).