# Firebase realtime database setValue() with data class including kotlinx.datetime.Instant field

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I am developing an Android application using Firebase Realtime Database.

According to [Firebase document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=ko#basic_write),

> Pass a custom Java object, if the class that defines it has a default constructor that takes no arguments and has public getters for the properties to be assigned.

So I made a custom Kotlin data class with `Instant` field as below :

```kotlin
import kotlinx.datetime.Clock
import kotlinx.datetime.Instant
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class UserStatus(
// ...
   val updatedAt: Instant = Clock.System.now(),
// ...
}
```

It has default constructor and only public getters.

```kotlin
val newUserStatus = UserStatus()
Firebase.database.reference.child(REFERENCE_USER_STATUS_NAME).child(createdUser.uid).setValue(newUserStatus).await()
```

But, because of `Instant` field of the class, the error occurs as below :

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid key: value$kotlinx_datetime. Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validateWritableKey(Validation.java:123)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validateWritableObject(Validation.java:106)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validateWritableObject(Validation.java:107)
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(DatabaseReference.java:283)
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:159)
//...
```

When I comment that `Instant` field and build, It works well.
What am I missing?

`Instant` has a default serializer.

I figured out that Firebase uses an internal property of `kotlinx.datetime.Instant` so the key includes `$`.

When I asked the same question on `kotlinx.datetime` repository, the maintainer answered me he thinks this problem is related to the Firebase, not `Instant`.[link](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime/issues/274#issue-1706869251)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already noticed, the error that you get is because of the following line of code:

```
val updatedAt: Instant = Clock.System.now()
```

And this is because [now()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx.datetime/-clock/-system/now.html) returns an object of type [Instant](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx.datetime/-instant/). Even if such a field has a default serializer and also exists in a class that is Serializable, it will always produce an error because such an object is not a [supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

While kllysmman's solution might work, as it will save a long value in the database, it will more elegant to save the date and time in the Realtime Database as a `timestamp`. To achieve that, please check my answer in the following post:

- [I need to add current date to firebase Realtime database with other data and retrieve all data with date in kotlin android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69416467/i-need-to-add-current-date-to-firebase-realtime-database-with-other-data-and-ret)

Comment: If I need to save a timestamp which is past, is it best option to save timestamp as @kllysmman's answer, right?

Comment: Then you have to save an epoch time that indicates that point in time.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, why? You have to understand that you are trying to save a complex Instant object which is obviously not compatible with the RealTimeDatabase saving standard. According to the documentation, you should simplify the database structure as much as possible.

```
val updatedAt: String = Clock.System.now().toString()
```

or

```
val updatedAt: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Wouldn't it be less expensive?

-Hugs