# How to parse iso8601 date-time in android kotlin or java

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime, iso8601

**Hello Devs,**

I'm working on **barcode** scanner app, I get date and time at this pattern **"20220610T230000Z"**
I think its **ISO8601** date-time format
However, I just want to parse this pattern so I can customize it as I want.

I tried this one:

```
val isoDate="20220610T230000Z" // from my barcode scanner
val df=SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
val date= df.parse("20220610T230000Z")
```

but when i run code i get

```
java.text.parseexception unparseable
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with. `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssX").parse("20220610T230000Z", Instant::from)` yields an `Instant` of `2022-06-10T23:00:00Z`.

Comment: I replaced `"uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssX"` with this pattern`"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"` cause it needs API 24 and i target API 21. Whatever it works well with me. how can i accept your comment as an answer? thanks @OleV.V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue solved
Thanks @OleV.V.

Solution
This pattern: `"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"`

Answer (score 0):

`isoDate` doesn't have any colons or periods in it. Since you're trying to turn `isoDate` into a `Date` object, you want something more like:

```
 val df=SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd'T'HHmmssSSS'Z'")
```

Then, if you want to output a date `String` with different formatting, you'll have to create a different `SimpleDateFormat` instance (let's call it `dt2`) with the intended formatting, and call `dt2.format(date)`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string) for a full example.

Comment: still get Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20220610T230000Z",
problem in that line -> val date= df.parse("20220610T230000Z")
i think this (yyyymmdd'T'HHmmssSSS'Z') is not the right pattern for my coversion

Comment: Oh yeah, you want to get rid of the "SSS" part.

Comment: still new in dates don't know what rid and what SSS but i just wanted to format this one then i can customize it i want and i solved it with this pattern `"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"`